# discord.py v2 app_command permissions

Tags: discord.py

I am creating a bot discord in **discord.py v2** and I have created app commands. I would like to make some commands reserved to administrators or to a certain role, but I didn't find how to do it. `@commands.has_permissions` does not work for app commands.

Can someone tell me how to do this please ?

My code :

```
    @app_commands.command(name="embed_message", description="Create a embed message")
    @app_commands.describe(
        title="The title of your message",
        message="Your message",
        color="Embed color",
        image="Add an image to your message (with image's url : http(s)://...)",
        url="Add an url to your message (http(s)://....)"
    )
    @app_commands.choices(color=[Choice(name=" Red", value=0xff0000),
                Choice(name=" Blue", value=0x0000ff),
                Choice(name=" Green", value=0x00ff00),
                Choice(name=" Purple", value=0x883af1),
                Choice(name=" Yellow", value=0xffe34d),
                Choice(name=" Orange", value=0xff8000),
                Choice(name=" Brown", value=0x845321),
                Choice(name="⚫️ Black", value=0xffffff),
                Choice(name="⚪️ White", value=0x000000),
                ])
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def embed_message(self, interaction = discord.Interaction, title:str="", message:str="", image:str="", url:str="", color:int=0xff0000):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        if title!="" or message!="":
            embed = discord.Embed(title = title, description = message, color = color)
            if image!="":
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=image)
            if url!="":
                embed.url=url
            await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)

        else:
            await interaction.followup.send("You must enter at least one title or message", ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this decorator before the slash command worked for me:

```
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(moderate_members=True)
```

(swap in your required permissions)